# Приложение закрывается при нажатии на back button

Tags: activity, android

Взял этот код с гугловской документации, но у меня вместо того, чтобы идти на предыдущую активити приложение просто закрывается 
вот сам код:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:

            Intent upIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            if (NavUtils.shouldUpRecreateTask(this, upIntent)) {
                 TaskStackBuilder.from(this)
                        .addNextIntent(upIntent)
                        .startActivities();
                finish();
            } else {
                NavUtils.navigateUpTo(this, upIntent);
            }
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: я что-то тут не вижу ни чего, что бы хоть каким-то образом относилось к нажатию кнопки back. Судя по всему, данный код запускает новую активити при выборе элемента из списка OptionsMenu,  или при клике на кнопку в Actionbar

Comment: Кнопка back не аппаратная, а которая в actionbar сверху бывает

Comment: а может происходит исключение и приложение падает? посмотрите в logcat.

Comment: > Кнопка back не аппаратная, а которая в actionbar сверху бывает

В терминологии Android, её принято называть `up button`, дабы не возникало путаницы с вышеупомянутой `back button`.

Comment: Исключений нет, увы. Это я сразу проверял

Answer (score 2):

Полагаю, вы не указали `parent activity` в `AndroidManifest.xml`. Пример, как это сделать, находится там же, в [документации](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#parent) (или же [тут](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)):

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.app.ChildActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_child_activity"
    android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
    <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support API level 4+ -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
        android:value="com.example.app.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

Comment: Да, проблема, скорее всего, в этом. Но дело в том, что параметр parentActivityName поддерживается только с SDK > 16 версии, а поэтому такой путь не получится использовать.

Comment: Вы в документацию принципиально не заглядываете?

> To support API levels 4 - 16, you can also declare the parent activity with a <meta-data> element that specifies a value for "android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY".

Пример с `meta-data` приведён выше.

Comment: Я принципиально изначально заглядываю в документацию. Так и реализовал изначально, вот этот вариант закрывает приложение

Comment: Но ведь чуть выше вы подтвердили, что у вас в `AndroidManifest.xml` для `<activity>` не указаны `parent activity`. Потому приложение и закрывается.

Comment: Нет, я написал, что не указал параметр "parentActivityName", который как раз для api > 16. Немного не так выразился

Comment: Для API 4-16 используется другой способ, о котором я писал выше. Что у вас сейчас не получается?

Comment: Я таким способом реализовал и этот способ не работает. Приложение закрывается